# How to set UITableViewCell Height according to UICollectionView Content size?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, contentsize

I have a **UITableView** and Inside that I have two `UICollectionViews`.

My requirement is that I have to scroll first `UICollectionView` Horizontally.
And I have to scroll `UITableView` vertically Because I don't want to scroll Second `UICollectionView`.

In Image you can see that first (Header 'Folder') `UICollectionView` I have to scroll horizontally and second (Header 'Product') `UICollectionView` I don't want to scroll vertically because I have to scroll Complete `UITableView`.

Both `collectionView` are in `TableViewCell` and I have disable scrolling of second `UICollectionView`.

I have to add and delete a product then I how can I set the `TableViewSecond` Cell height that content should come.

[image]

[image]

Here is my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if (0 == indexPath.section) {
        var addFolderCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AddFolderCell") as? AddFolderCell

        if(nil == addFolderCell) {
            let nib:Array = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("AddFolderCell", owner: self, options: nil)!
            addFolderCell = nib[0] as? AddFolderCell
        }

        addFolderCell?.collectionView.delegate = self
        addFolderCell?.collectionView.dataSource = self

        return addFolderCell!
    } else {
        let identifier = "CreateFolderCell"
        var createFolderCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? CreateFolderCell

        if(createFolderCell == nil) {
            let nib:Array = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CreateFolderCell", owner: self, options: nil)!
            createFolderCell = nib[0] as? CreateFolderCell
        }

        return createFolderCell!
    }
}

//Height for row.
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    //let index : NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(row: 0, section: 1)
    if 0 == indexPath.section {
        return 135
    }
    return 300
}
```

//Header height.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 20
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return sectionsArray[section] as? String
 }
}

extension GroupDataView : UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource {
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return 4
  }

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "AddFolderCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! AddFolderCollectionCell

    //cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.4
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 2
    //CreateCardView(viewCorner: cell.cardView) //cell.cardView
    return  cell
  }
}
```

//MARK: Collection View Layout

```
extension GroupDataView : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
     return CGSize(width: 90, height: 130)
  }
}
```

What can I do? How can I set the height for tableView?

Comment: tableView.rowHeight ? As defined in the storyboard ?

Comment: Yes but how can I set because second cell height according to second collectionView content size.
thanks

Comment: Looks like you're on the right direction  because overriding the ViewLayout methods should do the work.
The problem is to pass height of collection view cell to table view cell height ?

Comment: Yeah right.
How can I do?
Thanks

Comment: A UITableViewCell holds a UICollectionView, and now your use case is when you delete a UITableViewCell (that holds UICollectionView) you have no idea the height of the UITableViewCell that is depends on UICollectionViewCell height ?

Comment: Yeah .
But I don't want to delete any UITableViewCell.
Thanks

Comment: So what are you trying to do ? I am clueless..
If you are trying to remove collectionViewCell and adjust tableViewCell you have many ways to update the tableViewCellHeight by adding an observer to send a parameter (since collectionViewLayout is being called more then one time) or perhaps use delegate pattern.

Comment: Yeah .
Suppose Initially I have no collectionView Cell right.
After that suppose I added a collectionView cell and I want to increase height of tableView cell but how to calculate that how much height should increase ?

Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132300/discussion-between-ohadm-and-kishor0011).

Answer (score 2):

I think you can accomplish this, using some few steps:

1. Subclass your `UITableViewCell`, let's name it `CollectionCell`, and change it's class in IB interface to new subclass name.
2. Create outlet from `UICollectionView` to `CollectionCell` subclass, where `UICollectionView` is placed. Let's name it `collectionView`.
3. Add constraints to all sides of `collectionView` to cell bounds. (top, 
   right, bottom, left).
4. Add in IB for `collectionView` height constraint and create outlet to `CollectionCell` too. Let's name it `collectionViewHeight`.
5. In `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` add code:

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       // ...
       // normal cell declarations you wish
       // ...

       (cell as! CollectionCell).collectionView.reloadData()
       let height = cell.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
       (cell as! CollectionCell).collectionViewHeight.constant = height
       return cell
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
       return 100 // <- Your Desired Height
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
       return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
   }
   ```